# Update imageview on activitResult() method?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to update a `imageView` in my activity,the user clicks on the Imageview, Onclick of Imageview I am opening gallery to choose image, when user has selected the picture, it  returned to the previous activity with the selected image and uptate imageview.

But I am not able to update my imageview.

Can you suggest me where I am lacking, below is my code.

```
if(requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedpic = pic.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bmpic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver()
                    , selectedpic);
            ((BitmapDrawable)spic.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
            spic.setImageBitmap(bmpic);
            spic.invalidate();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post the answer as an answer and accept it whenever you can, don't just edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this line of code was wrong:**

```
if(requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

**it has to be:**

```
if(requestCode == RESULT_OK)
```